# changed local IP. Where am I supposed to update IP for minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I don't know why, but my local IP changed from `192.168.1.100` to `192.168.1.125`

So, when I start minikube, it starts well, but none of `kubectl` command works, it gives me:

```
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.1.100:8443: connect: no route to host
```

Where am I supposed to change the IP in my local computer ( ubuntu 19.04 ) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`minikube update-context` should fix this issue for you.

Quoting the docs:

> The update-context command retrieves the IP address of the running cluster, checks it with IP in kubeconfig, and corrects kubeconfig if incorrect

https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/commands/update-context/